# How to add a search method as command input

Tags: java, input, methods, command

I'm doing a program that adds participants, results for participants and events from sports competition. I want to be able to print out all the results for each event, by writing the name of the event as command. Then the program should search for the event in my `arrayList` and see if it exist, if it does it prints out the results. 
I have a method for searching the `arraylist` for the event, but i have trouble using a method as a command. I know it would be easier to use a common like `event result` or something and then add the methods there, but it is a requirement that you via command search for events in the list.

```
boolean running = true;
while(running) {
    System.out.print("Command> ");
    String cmd = readString().toLowerCase();
    if (cmd.equals("message")) printMessage();
    else if (cmd.equals("add participant")) addParticipant(); 
    else if (cmd.equals("check participant")) listParticipant();
    else if (cmd.equals("remove participant")) removeParticipant(); 
    else if (cmd.equals("add result")) addResult();
    else if (cmd.equals("participant")) listParticipantResult();
    -> //else if (cmd.equals(findEvent()) listEvent();
    else if (cmd.equals("end")) {
        System.out.println("Exit!"); 
        running = false;
    } else System.out.println("Wrong command!");

}
```

Comment: You should add an example of the command you can input and the methods that should be called (or how to use your search event method). For now, we can only assume for some pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Assuming that your command will be event name directly. ex. SportTornament

```
    // Above all if else
    //assuming cmd will be directly your event name. search for event name in eventList if it exists then call findEvent method with eventName( here it will be cmd) as parameter.

    } else if (eventList.contains(cmd)) {
        findEvent(cmd);
    }
```

---

Assuming your command will find

```
    //Above all if else
    //split the input as find saparate and other remaining string as eventName
    } else if (cmd.startsWith("find")) {
        String eventName = cmd.substring(4, cmd.length());
        findEvent(eventName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if you want to search for an event name and you expect a command to look like this: "find yourEventName", then all you need to to in your last `else if` statement is to check whether the command is "find yourEventName" and then split that String and only get the "yourEventName". When you have that just call your method `findEvent()` with the event name as a parameter and do in that method whatever you want with that event if you find it. Like this:

```
else if (cmd.equals("find yourEventName")) {
    String eventName = cmd.split(" ")[1];
    findEvent(eventName);
}
```

Hope this helps.